# I need a tag generated please

Tags: support, tags

I need a tag, [user-supplied-javascript], for my question *[How do I debug user supplied JavaScript code on Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827799)*.

This tag describe an essential part of the issue, as normal Javascript isn't hard to debug (and wouldn't justify a new question).

Comment: This seems really narrow to justify creating a tag. Any JavaScript gurus who could chime in?

Comment: A tag for any single issue would mean that we'd have millions of different tags.

Comment: Please take a look at [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944)

Comment: Askers rarely need a tag, the ones that use tags are answerers. I trust an answerer to create a tag instead of an asker.

Comment: _as normal Javascript isn't hard to debug_. it's even a pleasure.

Comment: Tags are only good if it already exists and people are watching it. So creating the new tag wouldn't help you out. And I don't think the distinction would be of use in future. Browsers present different ways to debug dynamic javascript at runtime. IIRC both Chrome and Edge have debug consoles that list downloaded javascript documents along side ones from plugins and virtual documents that contain dynamic javascript. That's where you need to investigate.

Comment: Please close. 4 comments and 1 answer is enough. I got the point.

Answer (score 8):

The [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag covers normal JavaScript.  We just happen to see it lumped with its partners [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) or [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) or [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) often enough that we forget this.

I don't see any value in adding this new tag.  It doesn't help us categorize questions in any way that doesn't already exist (and work well).